# Separability of $(\kappa,\mathfrak c)$-gaps in $\wp(\omega)/Fin$

Tags: set-theory

K. Kunen proved that it is relatively consistent with Martin´s Axiom that every $(\omega_1,\mathfrak c)$-gap and every $(\mathfrak c,\mathfrak c)$-gap can be separated in $\wp(\omega)/Fin$. What about $(\kappa,\mathfrak c)$-gaps, with $\omega_1<\kappa<\mathfrak c$?

Comment: In Kunen's model, there are actually no linear *pre-gaps* of type $(\omega_1, \mathfrak{c})$. This implies there are no linear pre-gaps of type $(\lambda, \mathfrak{c})$ for all regular $\lambda \ge \omega_1$ and so vacuously, all gaps of type $(\lambda, \mathfrack{c})$ ($cf(\lambda) \ge \omega_1$) are separated.

Comment: @NotMike, do you know what happens if the gap is not ordered?

Comment: Not really.The flexibility of the structure of non-linear gaps in models of $\mathsf{MA}$ is not particularly well understood. In the case of Kunen's model,  this structure depends how the $\diamondsuit$-sequence behaves when it fails to yield a satisfactory object.